# How to install UBUNTU on micro SD of Lenovo miix 310 ideapad?

Tags: lenovo, ideapad

I have a Lenovo MIIX 310 ideapad and I want to install the latest  LTS version of Ubuntu on a micro SD card and select Ubuntu vs its default Windows 10 in the bcdedit.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the latest LTS version of Ubuntu from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop.
2. Create an install media, either USB or DVD from the downloaded ISO.
3. Boot to the install media.  Make sure you are booting mode type `UEFI` so that the installer will recognize you want to install in that mode, which is required for dual booting your current Windows 10 installation.

    You may have to run off `Secure boot`.

4. Choose the `Try Ubuntu without installing` option for access to help with any problems during the install.  Then run the `Install Ubuntu` application on the desktop.

    Answer the preliminary options such as language.  When you get to the installation type, choose Install alongside Windows.
    If you don't see the Alongside Windows option, choose do something else.  The Do something else will give you the option of choosing the partition where you want to install Ubuntu.  For this you would have to create a partition by manually resizing the partitions you have and creating two partitions for the Ubuntu Installation.
    **Manually Create Ubuntu Install partitions**
    You can either use Windows Disk Manager or Ubuntu's Disk Manager (gparted).
    You can run gparted by type "gparted" in the Ubuntu search button.  There you will have a graphical user interface to resize, move, create, and delete partitions.  Create two partitions for the Ubuntu Installation.  One for the OS I recommend at least 50 Gigs.  And one for swap.  Make the swap partition about 1 1/2 the amount of memory you have.  If you have 8 gigs of RAM.  Make the swap partition about 12 gigs.
    Exit Gparted and run the Ubuntu Install again.  This time choose "Do Something Else" and specify the partition that you have chosen for your root "/" destination.

5. AFter following the installation prompts confirm to reboot the computer.  Choose `Ubuntu` in your BIOS boot option.  You'll have the option in the boot menu of choosing which OS to boot.
6. To have Windows as your default boot choice, count string with 0 to the boot choices on the screen.  If windows is the 4th one down, the count will be 3.  While in Ubuntu, edit your grub file and place your choice on the default boot line.

**Make Windows the Default Boot option**

Edit `/etc/default/grub`:

Change from:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

Change to:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=3
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

Now update your grub with:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Comment: converted Comment from @Vladimir-v I've managed to install it with those instructions, but have problems: 1) WiFi isn't working, lspci doesn't even show anything network-related 2) Windows boots by default even though I have GRUB_DEFAULT=0 set (by default)

Comment: Can you provide the name and manufacturer of the wireless adapter... or as much information as you can provide?  Can you provide a link to the output of `sudo lshw -c network`?  Also, keep in mind that (a possible catch 22) you may need all the current update drivers from the repository to have full access to the computer's hardware.  This will require a network connection... you may need to provide a wired connection for this part.

Comment: The main problem is that Ubuntu does not recognize the internal microSD reader. I tried using an external USB microSD reader for the installation then inserting the card into the internal reader, but then `grub` does not work at all and just opens a bash-like command line.

Comment: @Tooniis Will you provide the output of `sudo fdisk -l` into http://pastebin.com?

Comment: @L.D.James https://pastebin.com/7i3jaD2R here's the result of `sudo fdisk -l` when the SD card I installed Ubuntu on is connected to the miix 310 using a microSD to USB adapter (it is NOT in the internal microSD slot, and there are no cards in there).